# How to handle client side routing with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, single-page-application, html5-history

In node/express, I have this

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// start express module
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/*
 * Visit the home page
 */
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('My site started at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

And so I can only visit my page if I use the home link, or directly point to some file on the server.

However on the client side, I use single page application design with history API, and have a route for something like `localhost:3000/work`. So if I were to go to the root page, there is a button that uses history api to change the url to `/work` and it ends up showing new stuff.

However, if I visit `localhost:3000/work` maually, node.js thinks I need to find a file called `localhost:3000/work/index.html` or something and says page not found. How can I set it so that page requests still trigger the return of `index.html`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for not writing as a comment (i can't yet).

Not familier with your client side routes setup (can you share?).

This is not best practice, but just to make sure you're client side setup is ok - Can you just check that this is working:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
     res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: This just redirects to the home page, and removes the /work part, so it ends up showing home page stuff and not the work stuff.

Comment: do you have a state or a route in the client side of '/work/?
Can you share the code?

Comment: On the client side, it just checks the url, and sees the pathname is `/work` and hides the defaut div and shows the other div for work. If I start manually from the home page and use the history api pushstate code, to change the url, it works fine like that.

Comment: nevermind, your original code worked, I had some wrong path in my code.

Comment: Without using the history push api , can you try just to access a mock state or route of "/test"? If you use the history push API you might need to change some setting in the html5Mode.